# Fantasy movie with leprechauns

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't remember the name of the movie or really what it's about. I just remember bits and pieces. I think it was an older movie I watched back in the 90s. It was a fantasy movie with beautiful lands and forest and seas and I think I remember leprechauns.

One thing that keeps standing out to me is that there was a ship with a scary/intimidating fish or sea creature on a wall or in a case on the wall of the ship. The creature was golden with big teeth.

Comment: What about it was fantasy? Was it sword/sorcery or just the situation? Do you remember anything about the other characters?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMLy7SDi24M

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236949/fairy-tale-movie-series-where-a-villain-is-dispatched-with-a-poisoned-comb (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for this guy?

[image]

If so, the movie is The 10th Kingdom.  It was a miniseries that aired in the US in 2000.  I don't remember leprechauns specifically, but there are dwarfs (including a brief appearance by Warwick Davis).  The movie is halfway between a send-up of and an homage to classic fairy tales.

The fish above is hidden on a small boat, behind a secret door belowdecks.  There was a lot of time spent outdoors in the movie, and there were a few notable scenes in forests.

Comment: Thank u im watching it now to see if that was it you are a blessing

Comment: @robby - So...was it? :-)